# Passing Settings to AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is a good approach to pass setting to AngularJS app?

Technology stack:

- Node.js
- AngularJS

Settings look like this:

```
window.settings = {};
settings.webSocketURL = 'ws://domain.com/websocket';
settings.webSocketTopic = 'name';
```

Here are few options:

1. Include script
   `<script src="scripts/settings.js"></script>`

   Disadvantages: settings.js file is in scripts directory and not the root directory, additional script to load.
2. Include script like in 1 but settings.js is generated by Node.js.

   Disadvantage: additional script to load.
3. Embed setting directly into HTML.

   Disadvantage: need to use templating like EJS instead of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I solved using the config:

```
myapp
.constant("settings", {
  "webSocketURL": 'ws://domain.com/websocket',
  "webSocketTopic": "name"
})
```

then in your controllers you just have to inject the settings, and get them for example with `settings.webSocketURL`

Comment: That is good AngularJS way of defining settings, but it's not user-friendly for modifications by end-user. Ideally there should be settings file in the root web app folder that is modified according to user specific environment.

Comment: In that case you can consider using factories: this is a good example, is about page titles, but can easily adapted to your needs: http://maurizionapoleoni.de/blog/Setting-Page-titles-with-AngularJS.html

Comment: Yes. It makes sense to wrap setting into a provider, but the question is what is a good way to load data and may not be AngularJS specific question. I have config.js file that is used by Node.js application. Ideally I would want to make part of it (client-side settings) make available to AngularJS.

Comment: So far I'm leaning to my option 2. unless there is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create a config module anywhere you want

```
// config/app.coffee
angular.module('MyAppConfig', [])
  .config ($provide) ->
    $provide.constant 'webSocketURL', 'ws://domain.com/websocket'
    $provide.constant 'webSocketTopic', 'name'
```

And use a Grunt task, or script or whatever to concatenate it with your application script.

Comment: I'm using Grunt to build distribution (dist folder). Preferable way is not to use any concatenation for this. This settings file should be modified by the end-user who runs web application on user specific environment (user may not have grunt installed).

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your question.
Those settings are meant to be changed by a potential end-user of the application? If so, I think it really depends of the use case. How will the application be distributed, and how is it supposed to be deployed (just by opening the browser, running a local server, or uploading it to a "normal" server)?

Comment: I have config.js file that is used by Node.js application, app.js has var config = require('./config'); Ideally I would want to make part of it (client-side settings) make available to AngularJS.

Comment: So far I'm leaning to my option 2. unless there is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

- Put client settings in server config.

```
    config.settings = {};
```

- Generate JS file with Node.js

```
    app.get('/settings.js', function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
        res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        res.setHeader('Expires', 0);

        res.send('window.settings = ' + JSON.stringify(config.settings) + ';');
    });
```

- Define AngularJS constant

```
    ngular.module('app')
        .constant('settings', window.settings)
```